# Word count of text extracted from URL in Python

Tags: python, url, beautifulsoup, html-parsing, word-count

I am working on this NLP project that takes URL as an input and summarizes it using gensim library, But as for metrics of the summary that comes as output I want to calculate the word count of the original text taken from the website and word count of the summary generated. I have tried a few methods and I'm adding the code used below:

```
from gensim.summarization.summarizer import summarize
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen


def get_text(url):
  page = urlopen(url)
  soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml")
  text = ' '.join(map(lambda p: p.text, soup.find_all('p')))
  return soup.title.text, text

number_of_words = 0

url = input('Enter URL - ')
w = int(input('Enter Word Count of Summary - '))
text = get_text(url)

summary = summarize(str(text), word_count = w)

lines = summary.split()

number_of_words += len(lines)

print('\nSummary: \n\n', summary)
print(number_of_words)
```

Taking  https://www.ibm.com/in-en/cloud/learn/what-is-artificial-intelligence as the example URL, everything works well, except for getting the word count of **text** variable.

P.S. - The **word_count** count variable entered as a parameter, and the word count of the summary generated differs.

Also I have managed to get the text character length of original text retrieved from URL and summarized text using the code below:

```
print('Original text character length - ', len(str(text)))
print('Summarized text character length - ', len(summary))
```

Comment: I the the `word_count` parameter is meant to specify an upper-limit that it tries to get close to, rather than an exact length; and also , gensim probably doesn't count things like dashes `-` and articles like the/a/etc....

Comment: Answer at [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74492107/word-count-in-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74492107/word-count-in-python)